# Have written a code that is supposed to return true if at least one integer is even and false if otherwise

Tags: python

Full Problem: Write a function all which, again, takes a list l of integers as an argument. It should return True if at least one of those integers is even, and False otherwise. If l is empty, then the return value is trivially False. Your function should not modify the list argument in any way.

I have written the code but it keeps failing the following tests. Not sure where I am going wrong as it works for other tests.
The tests:

```
def test_ranges100(self):
        # All (except 1; all True)
        for n in range(2,101):
          arg = list(range(1, n+1))
          with self.assertUnmodified(arg):
            self.assertTrue(any(arg))

    # Odds (all False)
    for n in range(1, 101, 2):
      arg = list(range(1, n+1, 2))
      with self.assertUnmodified(arg):
        self.assertFalse(any(arg))

def test_simple(self):
    arg = [-5, -1, 10, 0, 1, 100]
    with self.assertUnmodified(arg):
      self.assertTrue(any(arg))
    arg = [-5, -1, 1, 101]
    with self.assertUnmodified(arg):
      self.assertFalse(any(arg))
    arg = [-10, 10, 0, -10, 10]
    with self.assertUnmodified(arg):
      self.assertTrue(any(arg))
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
def any(l):
  for i in l:
    if (i % 2 == 0):
      return True 
    else: 
      return False
```

Anyone know why my code is failing the tests above?

Comment: Yes, I know. But can you describe what your `any()` function is actually doing?

Comment: My any function is returning true or false if a value in list l is even, however I keep getting an error False is not True when I run these tests for my code

Comment: Yes, that's almost right. Your function is looking at the *first* value in the list and returning `True` if it is even and `False` if it is not even.

Comment: Ahh got it. How would I go about getting my function to look through every value in the list?

Comment: Well, you've got the first part right by iterating through the list with a `for` loop. The trouble you are having is that you are returning early with `return False` after the first item. You need to let the `for` loop continue if each item is not even.

Comment: btw I don't think you should name your function `any` since this will hide the built-in `any`.

Comment: I see. Would this mean putting return false outside the for loop? if so, what would i do with my else statement?

Comment: Ok, I've made you work hard enough, I'll provide an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only needs a simple modification:

```py
def any(l):
  for i in l:
    if (i % 2 == 0):
      return True 
  return False
```

The removal of the `else:` and unindent of the `return False` will mean:

1. The `for` loop will continue to find even numbers when the list starts with odd numbers.
2. The function will `return False` only at the end if the list contains only odd numbers.
3. The function will `return False` when the list contains no elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if this can be solved like so:

```
def exists_with_an_even(numbers):
    return any(x % 2 == 0 for x in numbers)

exists_with_an_even([1, 2, 3])
True

exists_with_an_even([])
False

exists_with_an_even([1, 3])
False

exists_with_an_even([5, -2, 1, 5, 7])
True
```